# WebApi call, client or server side?

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api, .net-core

I'm writing a .net core webapi for my customers. I'm interested to know if there is a way to understanf if a call comes from client-side (ie jquery) or server-side.

My intention is to avoid receiving client-side calls because I would like to prevent anyone from seeing the webapi URL from browser.

Can you help me?

Comment: what is the server kestral?   i think this only binds to localhost anyway : https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2016/sep/28/external-network-access-to-kestrel-and-iis-express-in-aspnet-core

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying to achieve this.

[image]

Most of the enterprise application deployed on a different server for scalability and security. If your API deployed on a separate VM then you can allow only your application VM to access it, this is the best and simplest solution.

**Other solution**

You can also pass some custom parameter on `httpClient` header and that parameter you can verify on web API (you can build a custom filter and apply to all Controllers).